# Can I autorelease an instance of NSProxy?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsproxy

Does `NSProxy` really implement `-autorelease` and `-release`? If not, do I need to manually `dealloc` `NSProxy` instances? (Please assume that I am not using GC).

Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it implements them.  NSProxy conforms to the NSObject protocol, which includes retain, release, and autorelease.  NSObject is not just a class, it's also a protocol.

```
@interface NSProxy <NSObject>
```

and in the NSObject protocol definition:

```
- (id)retain;
- (oneway void)release;
- (id)autorelease;
```